# I'm well aware of having been serially upvoted

Tags: support

I'm aware that I've been the target of serial up-voting.  Can I get a moderator to reverse it now?

If it doesn't get reversed now, I'll hit the rep cap very soon and be blocked from getting more.  Then tomorrow all that will be reversed automatically.  I will have answered many more questions tonight and the up-votes that I will likely get won't count because will already be at the cap.  Then when the votes get reversed, I'll lose that ill gotten rep but the other rep won't be compensated for.

This would be much easier if I could just get a moderator to reverse it now.

Comment: Moderators don't actually have the ability to reverse it. There's some tools with *limited* visibility but at the end of the day, either the system *or* a CM's going to do the vote invalidation.

Comment: This isn't how the system works. You will get the reputation from the legitimate votes instead.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I don't believe the problem you are worried about actually happens.

When the reversal script reverses the serial voting, it triggers a recalculation. In the process of doing this, it also recalculates the rep cap effect for the day, so any serial votes that get reversed do not impact the rep cap for the day.

I'm basing this answer off this meta post, in which someone appeared to have the problem, before it was properly recalculated: [Why Reputation is Locked After a Serial Up-Voting?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/24848/why-reputation-is-locked-after-a-serial-up-voting/24867)

Comment: Perfect.  I'll answer away then.